# Only allow positive or negative decimals in a field

Tags: jquery, regex

I currnetly have the following javascript whicih works perfectly for positive numbers and decimals, but it does not allow me to input a negative

```
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
```

I tried the following combinations with no luck. please help.

```
(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict input to numbers, use the HTML5 `number` input type:

```
<input type="number">
```

`this.value = this.value.replace` implies that you’re doing it on `input` or `keyup` or something similar, which really doesn’t work if users ever decide to move their carets.

You can always validate the entire thing *afterwards* for browsers that don’t support it:

```
var value = +someInput.value; // parseFloat(someInput.value) if you prefer

if (isNaN(value)) {
    // Not valid.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var re = /(?:\+|-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/gm; 
var str = '654654\n-654654';

str.match(re);
```

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/dY2sY1)

I reformulated your regex from `(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))` to `(?:\+|-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` because the groups are a little confused *(actually I think this is the problem, because there is a group inside other o.õ)*

**edit:**

there are more efficient ways to do this, like the other response [:

Comment: Why not `/[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?/g` ?

Comment: You don't need to escape it inside the character class.

Comment: yes, you are right, but there isn't any problem escaping, so it could be a "good practice"